# How can I use a XAML ellipse like a container for another shape?

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

I am creating a UserControl in WPF to model an eye (like a cartoon eye), and will move the "pupil" (black circle) around within the eye to look in certain directions. I would like to use the "white" part of the eye as the container for the "black" part of the eye, so that the black ellipse will be clipped as it gets to the edges of the eye, and won't just float outside of the white ellipse.

How can I do this in WPF/XAML?

[image: WPF Eye]

Answer (score 6):

You could use a `Border` with a large `CornerRadius` as the outer part of the eye and create an `OpacityMask` on that `Border` to make sure the inner eye is clipped to the `Border`

Quick Example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="121" Width="278" Name="UI">

    <Grid Background="DarkGray" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Border x:Name="opacityMask" CornerRadius="1000" Background="White" />
        <Border CornerRadius="1000" Background="White" >
            <Ellipse  Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Black"/>
            <Border.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=opacityMask}" />
            </Border.OpacityMask>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Result:

[image] [image]

Comment: Should this code here:

`<Border.OpacityMask><VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=opacityMask}" /></Border.OpacityMask>`

Read this instead?

`<Ellipse.OpacityMask><VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=opacityMask}" /></Ellipse.OpacityMask>`